# alfresco tomcat not getting started

Tags: java, tomcat, alfresco

I downloaded ***alfresco CMS*** for java and i installed it but the tomcat installed by alfresco is not getting started. and thats why i cant use alfresco.

in event viewer log it says **"The alfrescoTomcat service terminated with service-specific error 0 (0x0).
For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp."**

*anyone has solution for this ????*

Answer (score 2):

It [seems](https://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?t=17108) that unfit memory settings on the Windows Service can cause the issue you describe. To configure it, open the configuration window for the Alfresco service using (adjust the path accordingly):

```
C:\Alfresco\tomcat\bin\timcat6w //ES//AlfrescoTomcat
```

then on the Java tab try to adjust the values to fit your machine (e.g. you should not give the process more memory than the available physical RAM)

Comment: in my machine i removed my old tomcat and now alfresco tomcat tomcat6w is not opening it says "The specified service does not exist as an installed service."

Comment: i installed Alfresco in new machine in which tomcat was not per-installed and i also got the same error there....

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it best to break out tomcat from Alfresco and to install Tomcat separately with version that installs Tomcat as a service. There are .exe installers for this.

Apache Tomcat can be found

https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi

After Tomcat is installed start it up in Services.msc, then validate if the Tomcat console comes up. http://localhost:8080, then deploy your alfresco war file.

I like this approach better since I can verify tomcat before I deploy Alfresco.